# process.stdout.write / process.stderr.write monkey-patch works in child process but not parent

Tags: node.js, fs, node.js-stream, nodejs-stream

So I have this simple monkey-patch on `process.stdout.write` / `process.stderr.write`

```
    const strm = fs.createWriteStream(logfile);
    const stdoutWrite = process.stdout.write;

    process.stdout.write = function () {
      strm.write.apply(strm,arguments);
      stdoutWrite.apply(process.stdout, arguments);
    };
```

(for process.stderr, it's identical, and is writing to the same stream).

The problem:

When I run this process with `node x.js`

The stream does not complete all writing before closing, not even close.
However if I run

```
$ node y.js  # this runs x.js in child process
```

now the the stream running in the child will finish writing and the log file is now full.

Why would that be? Short of using `fs.appendFileSync`, is there a way to ensure that the stream will drain before the process closes?

**EDIT:**

I think I know why it's happening - I am calling `process.exit()` which will close the process prematurely, and will likely be called before the stream is finished.

Is there a way to listen for when the stream is finished writing? If call finish() on the stream when I call process.exit() that seems to be an artificial "finish". I tried waiting for the 'drain' event but it seems to never fire.

Answer (score 1):

Stream [`write`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback) and [`end`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_end_chunk_encoding_callback) can take a callback for when the operation is finished.

```
stream.end('end!', ()=> process.exit(0))
```

The [`drain`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_drain) event only fires once you can resume writing to stream that has previously failed/blocked.

I'm not entirely sure of the semantics of the `end`/`write` callback on failure. You might need to add a timeout, certainly if the write blocks the callback won't run until data is flushed.

```
stream.end('end!', ()=> process.exit(0))
setTimeout(()=> {
  console.log('end timed out')
  process.exit(1)
}, 2000)
```